# Regex to parse certain fields of a log file

Tags: regex

I have this log line:

```
blabla@gmail.com, Portal, qtp724408050-38, com.blabla.search.lib.SearchServiceImpl     .logRequest, [Input request is lookupRequestDTO]
```

I need to find a regex that grabs that email, then matches lookupRequestDTO ignoring everything in between.

Currently my regex grabs the whole line:

```
([\w-\.]+)@gmail.com,(.+)lookupRequestDTO
```

How do I not match anything in between the email and lookupRequestDTO ?

Comment: What language are you using? Add the `<tag>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using PCRE (php, perl, etc., and this should work in javascript):

```
([\w-\.]+?@gmail\.com),(?:.+)(lookupRequestDTO)
```

Out of capture groups 1 and 2, you'll get:

**MATCH 1**

1. `blabla@gmail.com`
2. `lookupRequestDTO`

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/yW9eU3

Comment: I need just the entire email and lookupRequestDTO and lots after that. This is mostly a sample line which is much much longer.

Comment: Then that regex will get you exactly that ;)

Comment: It's capturing too much.... the (?:.+). It's grabbing the last instance of lookupRequestDTO in the string. I need it to ignore everything between the email and the first lookupRequestDTO and ignore everything after.

Comment: The `?:` inside the capture group tells it to ignore what's there -- if you look the regex101 example you'll see.

Comment: @Rob that's JSON -- completely different case scenario? Use a JSON parser instead?

Comment: Ah, know almost nothing of JSON. Recommend where to start with this?

Comment: @Rob depends entirely on what language you're trying to parse it with, but a google search for `{language} parse json` will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
([^,]+).*?lookupRequestDTO
```

[^,]+ matches everything up until the first comma so it should get you the email

It assumes lookupRequestDTO is a criteria for your search. If it is a variable you want to retrieve, you could use this :

```
([^,]+).*?\[Input request is ([^\]]+)
```